# creation time for django model instance

Tags: python, django, model, django-queryset

how to know when an instance of django model has been created inside sqlite?
i tried many methods but i couldnt know or get when my db instance was created

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
time_threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=4)
results = x.objects.filter(created__lt=time_threshold)

i even tried this code but i got an error as below:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\momeir\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 941, in filter
return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\momeir\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\momeir\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 968, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "C:\Users\momeir\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1393, in add_q
clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
File "C:\Users\momeir\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1412, in _add_q
child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
File "C:\Users\momeir\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1286, in build_filter
lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
File "C:\Users\momeir\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1112, in solve_lookup_type
_, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
File "C:\Users\momeir\Anaconda3\envs\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1539, in names_to_path
raise FieldError("Cannot resolve keyword '%s' into field. "
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'created' into field. Choices are: contact_name, email_name, id, message, subject

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First question:*
if you want to inspect your database, so it is easy
every database have both GUI and CLI usually, so sqlite also have a GUI that you can download it in [sqlitebrowser.org](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

*also* your error say that your model dont have the *`created`* field so if it is not, give me more info.

```
qs = x.objects.filter(created__lt=time_threshold)

# to get number of objects only
n = qs.count()

# to get objects list
objs = qs.all()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, forget about the code I have shared , it won’t work since I have tried desperately the solution from other stackoverflow post . Simply I just want to query a queryset instance creation time and date , I can retrieve all data from queryset but there is no date time label when it was inserted to db so this is the issue